# React Native: How can I redirect after login to different pages depending on the type of account of a user?

Tags: react-native, authentication, user-accounts

I'm building a react native app using expo and I would like to know how I can send a "UserTypeA" to Homepage and send a "UserTypeB" to Profile upon login.

I have a UserTypeA tab navigator and a UserTypeB tab navigator, with just 2 pages that will be see able by both accounts.

I have my UserTypeA data and UserTypeB data in separate tables so I can identify which user has which type.

Sorry if it's not clear this is my first question.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your apps main render method, you could do something like this. 
Basically, you will listen to your redux state and switch main screen depending on the user type.

```
class MyApp extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { auth } = this.props;
    if (auth.userObj.type1) {
      return <Type1MainComponent />;
    } 
    if (auth.userObj.type2) { 
      return <Type2MainComponent />;
    }
    return <LoginScreen />;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { auth } = state;
  return { auth };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyApp);
```